# Trying to moveRowAtIndexPath into another section, iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)oldPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newPath {

    if(oldPath.section == newPath.section && oldPath.row == newPath.row) return;

    NSMutableArray * group = (NSMutableArray *) self.groups;
    NSMutableArray *gItems = [group objectAtIndex:oldPath.section];
    NSDictionary *item  = [gItems objectAtIndex:oldPath.row];
    [gItems removeObjectAtIndex:oldPath.row];
    gItems = [group objectAtIndex:newPath.section];
    [gItems insertObject:item atIndex:newPath.row];

    [self.tableItems moveRowAtIndexPath:oldPath toIndexPath:newPath];    
}
```

Trying to move rows between sections. however it crashes every time it runs the line `[self.tableItems moveRowAtIndexPath:oldPath toIndexPath:newPath]`, what did I do wrong? Ty in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out the problem.... just remove `[self.tableItems moveRowAtIndexPath:oldPath toIndexPath:newPath];` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have an "off by one" error:

```
if (newPath.row >= gItems.count) {
    [gItems addObject: item];
} else {
    [gItems insertObject: item atIndex:newPath.row];
}
```